# How to get the value selected in a select component to use it in another component using Vue

Tags: django, vue.js

I Have the following template

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5 filter big">
            <select v-model="stc" @change="getData" name="new" title="country">
                <option value="">all</option>
                <option v-for="country in data.countries_list" v-bind:key="country.id" v-bind:value="country.id">
                    {% verbatim %}
                        {{ country.name }}
                    {% endverbatim %}
                </option>
            </select>

        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-7">
                    travels
                    <p>
                        {% verbatim %}
                            {{ data.travels }}
                        {% endverbatim %}
                    </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The vue part is

```
 new Vue({
    el: `#${STSAppID}`,
    data: {
      data: {},
    },
    created() {
      this.getData()
    },
    methods: {
      refreshSelects() {
        refreshSelects()
      },
      getData() {
        const that = this
        const url = apiBase + "std/"
        axios.get(url).then(function(response) {
          that.data = response.data
          that.refreshSelects()
        })
      },
    },
    computed: {},
  })
```

What I want to do is check the selected value `{{ country.name }}` inside the other div `<div class="col-lg-7">` so being able to write something like

```
<div class="col-lg-7">
                    travels
***if country.name which is the selected option equals something then display the below p element***
                    <p>
                        {% verbatim %}
                            {{ data.travels }}
                        {% endverbatim %}
                    </p>
        </div>
```

can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There if [`v-if`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if)

you can test condition with it like this

```html
<div class="col-lg-7">
                    travels
***if country.name which is the selected option equals something then display the below p element***
                    <p v-if="stc === something"> <!-- 'stc' is v-model to select --->
                        {% verbatim %}
                            {{ data.travels }}
                        {% endverbatim %}
                    </p>
        </div>
```